# Can we install sybase on windows 7 laptop for learning purpose?

Tags: installation, sybase

I have an interview next week, It requires a person with expertise in PL/SQL and sybase basic. I have decent knowledge in PL/SQL and planning to learn sybase for the next few days. I was not able to find precise answers on sybase, kindly share your knowledge

1) Can we install sybase in windows laptop ? Windows 7.. any inputs for the same would be of great help

2) What is the most special feature of sybase, to be make it simple... y ppl use sybase when we have oracle/DB2/MS-SQL (NOM, asked to seek understanding).

3)Is there any language like PL/SQL for oracle with respect to sybase.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Oh boy..Looks like you are new here so I'll go easy.  This question is off-topic for a couple of reason, which is why someone downvoted it.  Please check out the FAQ for guidelines on appropriate questions.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should be able to download a developers version of SAP ASE (The Sybase name was dropped a few years ago).  I don't know about specific OS install options, but hopefully one will work for you, and if not get a VirtualBox VM to install it into.

2) It typically has lower administrative overhead then Oracle, but still a full enterprise dbms taking advantage of *nix stability.  At one point TCO was also lower than Oracle & SQLServer, but I'm not sure if that is still the case.  It also robust database replication support using SAP Replication Server, with lower overhead then many other replication options.

3) T-SQL is the SQL variant used by SAP/Sybase (as well as SQLServer).